# Add Images as Icons to PDF Document using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of the Acrobat JS call `doc.importIcon()` using PDF Box to import an larger number of images as icons into a PDF document.

I've already created and added an PDAppearanceStream to the AP Dictionary. 
Unfortunately the Icon is not accessible through `doc.getIcon()` JS call later in the PDF JS.

Maybe someone of you had the same problem. I guess I'm missing just a small piece here.

My current code looks like this:

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDDocumentNameDictionary nameDict = docCatalog.getNames();


COSDictionary dic = nameDict.getCOSObject().getCOSDictionary(COSName.AP);
COSArray names = (COSArray) dic.getDictionaryObject(COSName.NAMES);

PDImageXObject imgNeu = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(new File("C:\\FancyPicture.jpg"), document);
float width = imgNeu.getWidth();
float height = imgNeu.getHeight();

PDAppearanceStream pdAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
pdAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
try (PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdAppearanceStream))
{
    pdPageContentStream.drawImage(imgNeu, 0, 0, width, height);
}
pdAppearanceStream.setBBox(new PDRectangle(width, height));
pdAppearanceStream.setFormType(1);

COSArray defaultRes = new COSArray();
defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("PDF"));
defaultRes.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageC"));
pdAppearanceStream.getResources().getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, defaultRes);

Matrix mat = new Matrix(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
pdAppearanceStream.setMatrix(mat.createAffineTransform());

COSDictionary strDic = pdAppearanceStream.getCOSObject();
strDic.setString(COSName.NAME, "FRM");

COSString key = new COSString("img_01");
names.add(key.getCOSObject());
names.add(pdAppearanceStream.getCOSObject());
```

Comment: Could you share a PDF which has such icons, and your result PDF?

Comment: thanks for replying. I have already figured out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out as if the JS runtime within Acrobat requires the COSString elems encoded as UTF-16 incl. Byte order mark

After proper encoding of the icon names and using `COSString(byte[])` everything works as expected.